# Is it possible to change the date in one cell when another cell on another sheet shows another date?

Tags: regex, date, google-sheets, match, extract

On google sheets, I have 1 sheet that has a date range selected in two cells for one year, and then on the second sheet I have a date range for the next year. I was wondering if its possible to have:

sheet1!D2 and sheet1!D3 change to match sheet2!D2 and sheet2!D3. So if I select January 2023 in sheet2!D2 it changes the date in sheet1!D2 to January 2022 and then if I select April 2023 in sheet2!D3 it changes sheet1!D3 to April 2022

Tried conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you describe is called "reference" and it is possible to reference either one or multiple cells.

in sheet2!D2 if you select `January 2023` then use this in sheet1!D2:

```
=sheet2!D2
```

---

### update 1:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(sheet2!D2; "\w+ ")&REGEXEXTRACT(sheet2!D2; "\d+")-1
```

---

### update 2:

```
=DATE(YEAR(sheet2!D2)-1; MONTH(sheet2!D2); DAY(sheet2!D2))
```

Comment: Thank you! When I do that it shows January 2023 in Sheet1!D2. I want it to show January 2022 though. How would one change the year?

Comment: Thank you again! However, the date is a number (1/1/2022) and the formula is stating it can only pull text.